# remove multi line in text php

Tags: php, html, tags, line

when i try to get contact its look like this 
i want to remove multi line in this case

```
        $contents= "MULTIPLE CHOICE
    1 : _____ is defined as getting work done through others.
    A : Orientation




    B : 



                                Marketing




    C : 



                                Management "; 

echo $contents;
```

i do multi things but dose not work

```
$contents = preg_replace("/\/\/\n/", "\n",$contents);
$contents = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $contents));
```

and another code but dose not work

Answer (score 0):

to remove all white space and all line break  :

```
 $contents = preg_replace("/[\n\r ]/", "",$contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to see if your newline characters are not \n, for example checking for [\r\n] gets CR and Newline.

```
$contents = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $contents);
```

The + quantifier tells the pattern matcher to repeat the previous item once or more. So it'll grab all of the extras in a row and replace them with one.

For your space problem you can just run a

```
$contents = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $contents);
```

[This site has a lot of useful info on Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all i find the solution and the best solution is

```
   // removing any none word characters after ': xxxxx' and replace it with ': '
// this will remove all spaces and line brakes after ':'
$contents = preg_replace('/:\W+/', ': ', $contents); 
// removing any multiple white spaces including line breaks and replace it with single line break
// this will remove all spaces and line brakes after the answer
$contents = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", "\n", $contents);
```